# How can i serialize a Realm object which has a custom class

Tags: android, realm, parceler

I'm having a problem with building Realm object which has a custom class.

```
@Parcel(
    value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
    analyze = { Message.class })

@RealmClass
public class Message implements Comparable<Message>, RealmModel {`

@PrimaryKey
@Index
private long id;
@JsonProperty("thread_id")
long threadId;
@JsonProperty("message")
public String message;
@JsonProperty("user")
public User user;
...
}
```

When server send json response, try to parse as Message realm object with

```
realm.createObjectFromJson(MesssageMessage.class, JSONObject)
```

The problem is User. I've got an compile error "Filed user is not supported".

Below is the User class which is not realm object.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("incomplete_signed_up")
public class User implements KeepClassFromProguard, Parcelable {
public static final Parcelable.Creator<User> CREATOR = new
Parcelable.Creator<User>() {


    @Override
    public User createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new User(in);
    }

    @Override
    public User[] newArray(int size) {
        return new User[size];
    }
};

public long id;
@JsonProperty("account_id")
private long accountId;
@JsonProperty("display_name")
public String display_name;
@JsonProperty("nick_name")
public String nickname;
@JsonProperty("user_detail")
public UserDetail userDetail;

...
}
```

I read https://gist.github.com/cmelchior/ddac8efd018123a1e53a and http://parceler.org/#getting_parceler, but I could't get answer yet.
I can't change every class to realm object because they all have another custom classes.

Does anyone know how this is handled? Hope there is any good example.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All references in a `RealmModel` must reference other `RealmModel` classes. This is the only way we can persist them.

You can `@Ignore` the `user` field, but then it will not be saved by Realm.